# Symfony 2.0 with Memcache to store the cache files

Tags: file, symfony, memcached, storage

Im using symfony 2.0 and I want to use memcached instead to store the files on app/cache

Is there any config.yml instructions to do this?

Thank you very much for yours answers.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this. You can however, configure some bundle to store their cache in memcache instead of a file (doctrine2 for example).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Adrien, It would be nice, on my project I only have one bundle.  Can you explain me how to do that for my bundle?

Comment: First, explain to me why do you want the cache to be stored in memcache ?